# How to send GET from code to yourself?

Tags: php, get

On one php application that running on my server, I want to automatically *Pause* some action.

Normally, I need to click on a button to do this, but I want to add some code to do this automatically. So I will check what hour we have and then pause or run again.

Because this is not my app and the code is complicated - I want to send `GET` request from code to yourself.

Can I do this somehow using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`?

This is the `GET` that is sending when I press button:

```
http://xxx/index.php?Page=Schedule&Action=Pause&job=175
```

for example

```
if(check_date()){
   send GET request to Pause
}else{
   send GET request to RUN
}
```

Comment: check the cURL functions. You can send requests using them.

Comment: cURL is a flexible and powerful approach for making any http requests. For simple GET requests you could also try file_get_contents.

Answer (score 0):

Try sleep function

```
if(check_date()){
sleep(specify duration in seconds);
 }
 else{
 send GET request to RUN
 }
```

Comment: but how to send GET request from the code in the server?

Comment: You can use cronjobs at specific durations.

Comment: NO, the code is processing in crone, but I want to add extra line to check time and send GET request. But I don't know how to send this GET request?

Comment: the issue is that I want to send Get from the server not from the Web

Answer (score 0):

```
function get($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();  

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

    $output=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}

echo get("http://xxx/index.php?Page=Schedule&Action=Pause&job=175");
```

just call this get function when you want to send http GET request. it uses cURL to make it happen

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://xxx/index.php?Page=Schedule&Action=Pause&job=175');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well simple way to do what you are trying to do is perhaps create a form and submit it like this:

```
if(check_date()){

    echo "<form name='frm' method='get' action='http://www.zxc.com/index.php'>
            <input type='hidden' name='Page' value='Schedule'>
            <input type='hidden' name='Action' value='Pause'>
            <input type='hidden' name='job' value='175'>
      </form>";

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'document.frm.submit();';
    echo '</script>';
}else{
    //other thing you want to do
}
```